# Has anyone used this twitter api - http://www.twapime.com/

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

Has anyone tried this api ? I'm having some trouble implementing it on BlackBerry. Tweets do not always send and I cannot access posted tweets.

Here is my code -

```
private void twitterSetup(){

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
        req.setMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        XAuthSigner signer = new XAuthSigner("", "");
        signer.signForAccessToken(req, "", "");
        try {
        HttpResponse resp = req.send();
        if (resp.getCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
        Token accessToken = Token.parse(resp.getBodyContent());
        req.close();
        req = new HttpRequest("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.xml");
        req.setMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        req.setBodyParameter("status", "new message");
        req.setSigner(signer, accessToken);
        resp = req.send();

        Tweet[] twts = null;
        try {

            Credential c = new Credential("","","","");
            UserAccountManager uam = UserAccountManager.getInstance(c);
         List[] lists = null;
            ListManager ter = null;
            if (uam.verifyCredential()) {
                 ter = ListManager.getInstance(uam); //pode ser pela classe Timeline tambem.

                ListManager listMngr = ListManager.getInstance(uam);
                lists = listMngr.getLists();
                }


            ter.startGetListTweets(lists[0], null, new SearchDeviceListener() {
            public void searchCompleted() {}
            public void searchFailed(Throwable cause) {}
            public void tweetFound(Tweet tweet) {
                System.out.println(tweet);
            }
            });

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        else { }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }finally {
        try {
        req.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        } 

    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Got part of this working, I was attempting to send the same tweet after the other. Seems that twitter does not support non unique tweets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Here is the class im using to get the twitter content based on type and tag. method getContent is not the most elegant but it works. It just downloads and parses a json file.
Look at http://search.twitter.com/api/

```
public class GetTwitterContent implements Runnable {

    private String tag;
    private String type;

    public GetTwitterContent(String type, String tag) {
        this.type = type;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            Hashtable twitterValuesHashtable = new Hashtable();
            String serviceUrl = "";

            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TWITTER_CONTENT_TYPE_HASHTAG)) {
                serviceUrl = Constants.TWITTER_CONTENT_HASHTAG_CONTENT;
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TWITTER_CONTENT_TYPE_USER)) {
                serviceUrl = Constants.TWITTER_CONTENT_USER_CONTENT;
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = getContent(serviceUrl + this.tag);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(baos.toByteArray(), 0, baos.size(), "utf-8"));
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int counter = 0; counter < jsonArray.length(); ++counter) {
                JSONObject thisJsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(counter);
                TwitterResponse twitterResponse = new TwitterResponse();
                twitterResponse.setCreatedAt(thisJsonObject.optString("created_at", "na"));
                twitterResponse.setTweetText(thisJsonObject.optString("text","na"));
                twitterResponse.setFromUser(thisJsonObject.optString("from_user", "na"));
                twitterValuesHashtable.put(new Integer(counter),twitterResponse);
            }
            ServerContent.future.addContent(Constants.TWITTER_KEY, twitterValuesHashtable);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private ByteArrayOutputStream getContent(String url) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        // len = 0;
        try {

            javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection connection = (javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection) Connector
                    .open(url);
            connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            // connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            java.io.InputStream inputStream = connection.openDataInputStream();

            // inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int c;
            while (true) {
                c = inputStream.read();
                if (c == -1)
                    break;
                // ++len;
                baos.write(c);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return baos;
    }

}
```